# Designed Logo in 1995 for County Little League

Tags: logo, art

Good afternoon, 
I designed/ won a contest back in 1995 for creating the county that I lived in little league logo. Since then it has been used on their facebook page, etc.

A couple years ago I redesigned it on my own time without letting anyone know, just for fun, to give it a more modern feel. I recently noticed that the new logo is on their facebook page.

I'm not out to bring down the local little league, I just want to know if I should contact them about the new logo or if I let them know that I am selling the newly redesigned logo at so and so site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tough call... I was significantly involved in my son's Little League about 10 years ago, even became President one year. I happily donated design work (logo, banners, program, etc). Once I left the league, I let them keep everything I had created.

However, your situation is a little different. On one hand, if they just happened upon your new & improved logo on the web, and took it from your site without asking, you have a right to tell them to basically "cease and desist" using it... although I don't really know if you'd really have a legal leg to stand on.

On the other hand, it's just Little League baseball, a non-profit organization. If it were me, I think I'd let them know that I don't mind if they keep using the new logo, but also that I don't really appreciate them taking the new version from my site without asking.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I do agree with you. Like I said, I'm not out to cause an uproar and disrupt the county little league, but my new logo is for sale would like to tell them where to buy it any of the parents, coaches, players would like to purchase. Thank you again for your quick reply and help.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about that part... how is the logo for sale to anyone other than that little league? Isn't it specific to them? Or would you just reuse the logo and replace the name? Because if that's the case, I might amend my answer... but I guess it depends on how close to the original your new logo is.

Comment: The updated design is online (it's locked and currently only I can buy it. Should have mentioned that) on a site that prints designs on everything from t-shirts to stickers.

Comment: So where did they get it? Possibly just stumbled across it on that site, and downloaded the image for their own website?

Comment: I posted it to Facebook when I first made it. I come from a very small town so even word of mouth via technology gets around quickly.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, I'd make a call to someone who runs the league and raise your concerns with them. Maybe if you could suggest a compromise, give them a discounted cost (seeing as they are a local non-profit, and you are interested in seeing them succeed, but that way you'd still make a little profit for your work. Again, not knowing how close the original is to your update, hard to say if you could still realistically keep it for sale on the other site though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a first time user on Stack Exchange, so I appreciate the help and comments you've given me.